# Exceptions to Rules of Parallelism

Tags: grammar, comparisons, parallelism, is-it-a-rule

Ok, it all starts with this thing we learned back in our elementary school that is called parallelism.  What it basically says is that you can’t compare a thing to a person and vice versa.

But here is something I personally think is different from parallelism, but am not so sure if it is. Is it correct to say:

> I am in accord with your opinion.

Or it should that instead read:

> I am in accord with you about your opinion.

Comment: You're like a stuck record. Who says people and things aren't comparable?

Comment: They aren't. At least on SAT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As someone who is bilingual in English and French, I would say there is a sentence in French which is exactly equivalent to the sentence you are trying to make:

> Je suis d’accord avec votre opinion.

But your literal translation of that sentence in all my years I have never heard as such in English. Even though it may not be grammatically incorrect I’m pretty sure it’s not common language usage.

Having a quick look at [the Free Dictionary entry for *accord*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/accord), I would say that an English equivalent would more be (because the English always reverse around how the French say it) a passive version of the active sentence you’ve given:

> You opinion accords with mine.

On the freedictionnary you can find an example that resembles the most your sentence under Translations (you have to scroll down a bit) for *accord* verb:

> His story accords with what I saw happen.

You put yourself at the end of the sentence, and the object of the action at the beginning.

Just my two cents worth — I’m open to debate about this.

By the way, if my English teacher ever heard me say either of your sentences, he would probably call it a Frenchism, something us bilinguals do a lot. When you literally translate a French sentence into English word for word, because the words have different meanings, the sentence itself loses its original meaning.

For example, in English, it makes sense to say:

> You should pay attention.

But if you translate each word into French:

> Tu devrais payer attention.

Then makes no sense at all, because in French one does not “pay” attention: the French verb for *pay* is used only with payments and currency and such.

In this case it would actually be an Anglicism, which is same as a Frenchism but the other way around.

Comment: Guess I got to read more english literature...

Comment: You make a very valuable point here that a monolingual person would not necessarily realize is true, so thanks for your perspective as a bilingual speaker. I’ve tried to lightly copyedit your posting for formatting and simple orthographic matters (read: spelling, capitalization, punctuation) without changing its intent in any way; if I have erred, please feel free to change anything you please.  By the way, the fancy word for what you call a *“Frenchism”* is a ***Gallicism***.  I suppose some people might call an ***Anglicism*** an *“Englishism”*.

Comment: I am not quite in accord with you. ;)

Comment: Native english speakers would never say "I am in accord with you about your opinion." You probably already get the sense that that sentence is too bulky. Something more like, "I think we are in accord," is still an elegant way of saying it (if you are going for elegant), or a more casual, "I agree," for everyday speech. Skirting around parallelisms is a legitimate tactic, I think!